# flash iframe overlay problem in windows

Tags: flash

I've got a div over an iframe, in the iframe there's a website that contains a youtube movie.
On mac firefox and safari everytyhing works fine, on windows both IE and FF put flash on top of my div.

The situation I have is really similar to google image interface, I noticed that google images manages to correctly overly an immage over a website with flash content in any browser both win and mac.

How they manage to do that? Considering they have no access to iframed page code.
I tried reading their code to find solution with no success.

Thanks

Giuseppe

Answer (score 0):

To handle that reliably, you need to load your Flash via Javascript...

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

and pay attention to the fact that you need to set wmode to transparent:

from examples...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var so = new SWFObject("movie.swf", "mymovie", "400", "100%", "8", "#336699");
  so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
  so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I always use swfobject and wmode transparent, the problem here is that I have no control over the iframed page.